# The object does not connect to the server

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public class Rabbit
    {
        public IConnection GetConnection(string hostName, string userName, string password)
        {
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.HostName = "1.2.3.4";
            connectionFactory.UserName = "login";
            connectionFactory.Password = "pass";
            connectionFactory.Port = 5672; 
            return connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        }

        public  void Send(string queue, string data)
        {
            using (IConnection connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection())
            {
                using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue, false, false, false, null);
                    channel.BasicPublish(string.Empty, queue, null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

                }
            }
        }

        public  string  Receive(string queue)
        {
            using (IConnection connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection())
            {
                using (IModel channelconsumer = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channelconsumer.QueueDeclare(queue, false, false, false, null);
                    BasicGetResult result = channelconsumer.BasicGet(queue, true);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body);
                        Console.WriteLine(data);
                        return data;
                    } else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I run my code:

```
var rabbit = new Rabbit();
rabbit.Send("sample.queue.queue", json);
```

My RABBIT object connects to the localhost, not the server whose configuration is in GetConnection.

Can I ask you to correct this code?
Login details are correct in my code.

Comment: I changed here. In my code, I have correct data. Maybe the GetConnection function does not call correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you consume the `GetConnection` method, you just create a completely separate `ConnectionFactory` which makes it use default values.

Looks like you should replace

```
using (IConnection connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection())
```

with

```
using (IConnection connection = GetConnection())
```

Comment: Now I have error in line: return connectionFactory.CreateConnection(); - 
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: „None of the specified endpoints were reachable”. AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

Comment: The error suggest you have incorrect endpoint details. Are you sure the IP/port address and login credentials are correct?

Comment: Ok. It's working :) Now I have error in line: sample.queue.queue' in vhost 'centralDev' not equivalent - RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: „The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - parameters for queue 'insurance.motor.interrisk.calc' in vhost 'sample.queue.queue' not equivalent", classId=50, methodId=10, cause=”

Comment: This topic might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410985/exception-the-amqp-operation-was-interrupted-code-406-occurs-in-net-client

Comment: Different errors should make separate questions, that way others looking for `ACCESS_REFUSED` or `PRECONDITION_FAILED` will find full questions with appropiate answers.